# SQL Server 2008 R2 sp_replmonitorrefreshjob Issues

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, merge-replication

My team just moved our production SQL Server VM from one machine to another. During the move we also applied server updates. After the move was completed, everything tested as a successful move.

Today I found the job "Replication monitoring refresher for distribution" running for over 24 hours. The procedure that it is hanging on is sp_replmonitorrefreshjob. This slows all the user and developer queries.

How can I troubleshoot this? It's not producing an error, it's just sits in a permanent suspended state with query waitfor delay @strdelaytime

Comment: That sp runs continuously - see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152762.aspx). Just stop the job and it will start again.

Comment: Did that.  It was kind of weird, but eventually it just stopped being an issue.